# xmlreader skip sibling

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I use Xmlreader to parse a xml file.

My method look like

```
string path = @"E:\tmp\testxml.xml";
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
{

    bool isOnNode = reader.ReadToDescendant("resource");
    while (isOnNode)
    {
        var element = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(reader);

        isOnNode = reader.ReadToNextSibling("resource");
    }
}
```

But xmlreader skip the sibling node "resource". 
Moreover when I open the xml file with visual studio, indent and save it, nodes aren't skip.

Comment: Please tag the question with the appropriate language tag.

Comment: Please also provide the contents of the XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `XNode.ReadFrom` method places the reader after the closing element of the subtree it read. If there is no whitespace in the file, this will be the next `<resource>` element. This element is then skipped by the `ReadToNextSibling` call.

The following should fix it:

```
string path = @"E:\tmp\testxml.xml";
using( var reader = XmlReader.Create(path) )
{

    bool isOnNode = reader.ReadToDescendant("resource");
    while( isOnNode )
    {
        var element = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(reader);

        if( !reader.IsStartElement("resource") )
            isOnNode = reader.ReadToNextSibling("resource");
    }
}
```

If there are no non-`<resource>` elements as siblings of the `<resource>` elements, the problem can also be solved simply by using `IsStartElement` in the while-loop condition.